# Matlab how to read txt data file into workspace

Tags: matlab

The txt file is organized in the following format:

```
image filename
n (number of objects of interest in the image) 
bounding box for object 1
bounding box for object 2
...
bounding box for object n
```

For example, the contents in the txt file are listed as follows:

```
images/1.jpg
1
39.284331   23.721327   88.000000   135.915360
images/2.jpg
4
107.912089  129.898400  62.372022   89.263200
186.266100  61.768245   64.831800   106.847910
298.909724  34.289100   73.830894   105.977200
135.454600  -63.205613  109.739600  176.375026
images/3.jpg
2
136.462492  18.762699   121.522126  187.348778
333.601798  18.139177   104.944018  155.239682
```

I now want to read the file into a into a structure data (N*1, where N is equal to the number of images) with three fields, file name, number of objects and bounding box.  Is there some efficient way to achieve that?

Comment: with "number of interest" do you mean number of "bounding boxes"? what are your attempts/thoughts so far?

Comment: You are right. N is the number of bounding boxes. Each row following N corresponds to one bounding box (xmin, ymin, width, height)

Answer (score 1):

There is not an easy way to parse the file and keep the headers.  You can use textscan to grab the data for each entry, but you don't get the headers.  This might suite your needs, but I'm guessing you'll want the filenames for the corresponding bounding boxes.  Mathworks documentation on this can be found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/import-large-text-files.html?s_tid=srchtitle).  In your case, this is easily parsed using

`A = textscan(fid,'%f %f %f %f','HeaderLines',2)`.
This can then be repeated until you get to the end of the file.

Alternatively, you can use `fgetl` in conjunction with `textscan` to first parse the headers, and then read the block data in.  An implementation is found below.  Note that the below implementation assumes each block comes one after each other with no spaces.  You may want to add more robustness to this depending on your use case.

```
function [ data ] = parseTestSO( filename )

fid = fopen(filename);
% automatically close the file when cleanupFunction goes out of scope
cleanupFunction = onCleanup(@()fclose(fid));

% define the struct

n = 1;
while ~feof(fid) % repeat the read until all entries are parsed
    data(n).filename = fgetl(fid); % gets the filename
    data(n).numEntries = str2double(fgetl(fid)); % gets the number of entries
    tempVal = textscan(fid,'%f %f %f %f'); % read formatted data block until next non-matching line

    data(n).values = [tempVal{:}]; % transform the returned cell array into an nx4 array
   n = n+1;
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fileID = fopen('yourfile.txt','rt');
data = textscan(fileID,'%s','delimiter','\n');
C = data{1} ;
fclose(fileID);
IdxC = strfind(C, 'images');
Idx = find(not(cellfun('isempty', IdxC)));
nimages = length(Idx) ; % total number of images 
iwant = struct ;    % initialize structure

for i = 1:nimages-1
    iwant(i).name = C{Idx(i)} ;
    iwant(i).no_objects = str2num(C{Idx(i)+1}) ;
    iwant(i).bounding_box = C((Idx(i)+2):(Idx(i+1)-1)) ;
end

iwant(nimages).name = C(Idx(nimages)) ;
iwant(nimages).no_objects = C(Idx(nimages)+1) ;
iwant(nimages).bounding_box = C(Idx(nimages)+2:end) ;
```